# Connect Azure Web App to policy-based VPN

Tags: vpn, azure, connection, azure-web-apps, point-to-site-vpn

I have an Azure Web App that needs to connect to the addresses xx.x.x.10 and xx.x.x.12 the customers on-premise server.
For this purpose the Customer have setup a **Policy based VPN** (Cisco ASA 9.8) with public IP yyy.yy.y.y

While trying to get to obtain this connection to the on-premise service, I have for now created the following resources:

- a Local Network Gateway with

  - IPaddress yyy.yy.y.y
  - Address spaces xx.x.x.10/32 and xx.x.x.12/32
- a VNet with

  - Address space 10.0.0.0/16
  - GatewaySubnet 10.0.255.0/24
- a Public IP: zzz.zz.z.z
- a Virtual Network Gateway

  - Sku: Basic
  - VPN: **PolicyBased**
  - Subnet: GatewaySubnet (10.0.255.0/24)
  - Public IP: zzz.zz.z.z
- a Site-to-site connection between the Local Network Gateway and the Virtual Network Gateway

Since the Virtual Network Gateway needs to be Policy-based, it (as I see it):

- has to be Basic Sku
- is restricted to maximum one site-to-site connection
- cannot have point-to-site connections

Will it somehow be possible for me to get my web app in contact with the on-premise server?
and in that case that what am I still missing to make it work?
or is it required that the VPN is changed to a route-based?

Answer (score 0):

You can [directly connect your Web App with your Virtual Network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) if they are in the same Azure region. This will allow the Web App to talk with anything connected to the VNet, including remote networks reachable through site-to-site VPNs:

[image]

A point-to-site connection is only required [if the VNet is in a different Azure region or uses the Classic deployment model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#gateway-required-vnet-integration).

Comment: Great, all my Azure resources are in the same region, so this seems to be the on the right path.
Is it correctly understood that I should create an additional subnet on the VNet and connect the Web App to this subnet? - or should I connect to the already created GatewaySubnet to which my Virtual Network Gateway is connected?

Comment: You need an additional dedicated subnet; the GatewaySubnet can only be used by a Virtual Network Gateway. You'll find sizing guidelines for the integration subnet in the documentation (although, since you have the whole 10.0.0.0/16 address space available for the VNet, just choosing any 10.0.X.0/24 is the easiest way to go).

Comment: So i dont need a point to site config, if it is in the same region? Is this true? I have trouble with my setup, and i dont know if i should see anything specific after connecting the webapp to rhe vnet, like routing info etc beside the subnet information.

Comment: Yes, it' true. And no, the only thing you'll see is the fact that the Web App is connected to the VNet. Everything should *just work* if you set it up correctly. If you have troubles, please post details in a new question so that we may help you.

Comment: Thanks. I have done so: https://serverfault.com/questions/1054000/azure-webapp-site-to-site-vpn-not-working-when-used-with-webapp